# To show $m \mid \sum_{i \in (\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{m \mathbb{Z}})^*} i$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $m\geq 3$, I need to show that  $ d \equiv 0 \ mod \ m $ where $d=\sum_{i \in (\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{m\mathbb{Z}})^*} i$ .

That is if we sum all elements in the group of units in $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{m\mathbb{Z}}$,then it divisible by $m$.

Comment: Don't confuse $\frac{\Bbb Z}{m\Bbb Z}$ with $\Bbb Z_m$.

Comment: Isn't $\;\Bbb Z_m\;$ the usual, though sometimes misleading, way most students, in particular beginning ones, denote the quotient group (ring) $\;\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z\;$ ?

Comment: @AhmedHussein Which "two" are you talking about? The only other more or less usual meaning to $\;\Bbb Z_m\;$ I know of is the $\;m$- adic integers, though it is more usual to use $\;p\;$ instead of $\;m\;$ .

Comment: Don't you rather want to show $\sum_{i\in(\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z)^*}i=0$? After all, the sum is certainly an element of $\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z$, not of $\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sum $$\sum_{i\in(\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z)^\times}\!\!\!\!i\quad\in\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z $$
note that if $i$ occurs as summand then so does $-i$. Moreover, even if $m$ is even, $m/2$ is not a unit (that would only be the case with $m=2$, which is excluded), hence by associating $i$ and $-i$ we pair off all summands. As each such pair sums to $0$, so does the whole sum.

Comment: Ah, this is nice: I think it uses $\;(k,m)=1\iff (m-k,m)=1\;,\;\;1\le k\le m\;$ , right?

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

== $\;G:=\Bbb Z_m^*\;$ is a multiplicative group

== If you choose $\;1\neq k\in G\;$ , then

$$T:=\sum_{i\in G}i=\sum_{i\in G}ki=k T$$